# c++ string clear() after declaration

Tags: c++, string

I am a beginner learning strings.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
string st1, st2;
st1.clear();
..
```

I have seen in several examples the use of clear() after a string declaration. Is it necessary? Does this provide any benefit or is just a good practice, isn't the string null by default after declaration?
Thank you.

Comment: It does not do anything, nor is it good practice.

Comment: _" isn't the string null by default after declaration?"_ - it will be empty. Strings can't be null, only pointers can.

Comment: cargo cult programming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A default-constructed string has [zero size and unspecified capacity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string), so semantically, there is no point in calling `clear()`. The string was empty and cannot be made more empty.

However, [it is not guaranteed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/clear) that `clear()` does not change the string's capacity, so it's possible that some implementations free up some memory when calling `clear()` on an empty string. cppreference claims that "existing implementations do not change capacity" so even this reason to call `clear()` is probably invalid.

In short, do not follow these bad examples.

Comment: I doubt that clear() would change the capacity versus default c'tor, but wouldn't shrink_to_fit be a much more appropriate choice?https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/shrink_to_fit

Comment: The strings in the compilers I use have the small string optimization (SSO), so the reserve capacity is baked into the small string.

Answer (score 2):

This is not necessary. The `std::string` default constructor initializes the object to an empty string. `clear` empties an existing string. That is senseless on an default constructed empty string. It is just a waste of time (if the compiler does not optimize the call away).